# How to fetch those agent ids efficiently in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join

Check following section is model related sections :

```
ALL_STATUS = ['approved', 'pending', 'processing', 'declined', 'rejected']

#agent.rb
has_many :reports 
has_many :assessments, through: :reports

#report.rb
has_many :assessments 
belongs_to :agent

#assessment.rb
belongs_to :agent

Those are my sample records in DB.
#agent
id  name 
1  Alex
2  Justin
3  Clark
4  Mike

#reports
id  agent_id   status 
1     1        approved
2     1         pending
3     1         processing
4     1        rejected

#assessment
id report_id agent_id  status 
1    1          1       approved
2    3          1       processing
3    2          1       pending
4    4          1       rejected
```

Desc:

- once we create reports those are getting converted to assessment
  record.

  2. Here reports submitted by agent#Alex(user_id: 1) has been added for assessment.
  3. I want to find out those UserIDs whose all assessments are not Yet added / Reject those user_ids whose reports are already added to
     assessment List?
  4. So here output will be only [2,3,4]. (those ids might have reports record but may not have any assessments)

I am using following code to get those agent ids.

```
eligible_agents = []
result = Agent.joins(:reports, :assessments)
  result.each do |agent|
    if(agent.reports.pluck(:status).count !=agent.assessments.pluck(:status).count)
      eligible_agents.push agent.id
    end
  end
```

Here the problem is clearly visible, if number of reports/assessments grows then query present inside if condition is going to run multiple times.

What better solution we can have here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will return any Agent who does not have an Assessment:

```
Agent.where.not(id: Assessment.all.pluck(:agent_id))
```

Is this what you were looking for?

If you need just the Agent ids:

```
Agent.where.not(id: Assessment.all.pluck(:agent_id)).pluck(:id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going though `Agent` you want to get all reports that don't have associated assessment. Then grab agent_ids from that list. I think `joins` does an inner join by default, so you need to specify left join condition and filter things that are missing assessments. Then you can just `pluck(:agent_id)` out of that.